# print deque containing multimap

Tags: c++, multimap, deque

I would need to print a dequeu containing a multimap, but it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
    deque<multimap<string,int> > q_map;
    multimap<string,int> m;

    m.insert(pair<string, int>("a", 1));
    m.insert(pair<string, int>("c", 2));
    m.insert(pair<string, int>("b", 3));
    m.insert(pair<string, int>("b", 4));
    m.insert(pair<string, int>("a", 5));
    m.insert(pair<string, int>("b", 6));
    cout << "Map size: " << m.size() << endl;

    q_map.push_back(m);
    for (std::deque<int>::iterator it = q_map.begin(); it!=q_map.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
}
```

I am always getting a compiler error:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::_Deque_iterator<std::multimap<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > >, std::multimap<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > >&, std::multimap<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > >*>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*>’ requested
q_map.cpp:23: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘it != std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::end() [with _Tp = std::multimap<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::multimap<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > >]()’
```

Comment: I added the compiler error I am getting.

Comment: `std::deque<int>::iterator`? Why `int`? If you have a C++11 capable compiler consider using [range-based `for` loops instead](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), or the very least e.g. `const auto it = q_map.begin()`

Comment: Also, when you fix the above error you will get new errors as you're trying to print a `std::multimap` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this type:

```
deque<multimap<string,int> > q_map;
```

But you're trying to iterate over it with this type:

```
for (std::deque<int>::iterator it = q_map.begin(); ...
```

That's what you're doing wrong.

If you can't use the C++11 range-based `for` loop, or the C++11 `auto` feature, then instead of repeating the type `multimap<string,int>` everywhere, you can use a typedef for it:

```
typedef multimap<string,int> mmap;
```

Now you can refer to `std::deque<mmap>` everywhere you use it, so the `for` loop would use a `std::deque<mmap>::iterator`

Answer (score 1):

Well, two simple for loops, one to iterate over the `deque`, and the other to the `multimap`:

```
for ( auto it = q_map.begin(); it != q_map.end(); ++it )
    for ( auto it2 = (*it).begin(); it2 != (*it).end(); ++it2 )
        cout << ' ' << it2->first << ' ' << it2->second << endl;
```

Or with range loops

```
for ( auto& it : q_map )
    for ( auto& it2 : it )
        cout << ' ' << it2.first << ' ' << it2.second << endl;
```

Comment: great, that would work if I could use c++11, but I cant update the compiler.